# bash: /SetUpFreeSurfer.sh: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04, bash

```
bash: /SetUpFreeSurfer.sh: No such file or directory
```

I tried to install FreeSurfer software in my Ubuntu 18.04 system that didn't go well. Till then whenever I open up my terminal I am seeing this error message.

I have used the following installation guide: https://surfer.nmr.mgh.harvard.edu/fswiki/DownloadAndInstall

I think this line here messed up my bash: 
`$> source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably haven't remove them on your `.bashrc` file, this causes the line to execute every time you open a terminal.

- Open `.bashrc` using your favorite text editor

  ```
  gedit .bashrc
  ```
- Locate for line containing `source $FREESURFER_HOME/SetUpFreeSurfer.sh`.
- Manually remove the line, then save and close the file.
- Execute following command on terminal.

  ```
  source .bashrc
  ```
- Try open new instance of terminal.

Comment: Thanks! that worked. 
One other thing, could you help me to understand the FreeSurfer installation procedure?
I am a beginner in Ubuntu and bash script commands.

Comment: @banikr Save that for new [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/ask), though the documentation cover that pretty clear.